# I cannot get wifi working Dell Vostro 3550 running Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers

I cannot get wifi working on my Dell Vostro 3550 running Ubuntu 14.04 does anyone know of a driver?

Edit: Intel Corp Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Welcome to askubuntu!

Comment: Intel Corp Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome unfortunately I'm Thee Ultimate Noob in Linux. I have used only Macs since 1989 and know very little command line.

Comment: No problem. I'm here to guide you. Does rfkill list all give us any clues?

Comment: Soft blocked No, Hard Blocked Yes

Comment: Please help us help you by editing your question to include the complete output of the information that we request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hard blocked: yes* in rfkill suggests that the wireless is hardware blocked; in other words, the wireless switch or key combination is set to disable wireless. Please find the switch or key combination and enable the wireless.

The device in question, Intel Corp Centrino Wireless-N 1030, should work by default in Ubuntu 14.04 with no further driver or firmware installation required.

Comment: Wow thanks! I did find a FUNC key combo press that showed a wifi symbol. My wifi is working now! I got this machine for free from our IT guy literally 2 1/2 hours ago and I knew I didn't want windows on it so he wiped the drive and I had made a "Trusty" usb installer prior knowing he was going to recycle it so asked if I could have any old computers he was trashing, and he gave me an i5 with 4 gb  and a 320hdd. I think this is a 2011 with an HD3000 and I think it may have a discrete card as well but system profiler doesn't show a lot of info unlike OS X. I have to dig into this.

Comment: Awesome! If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Do you know the correct driver/firmware it should use? Thanks.

Comment: @DrBeco The driver for the device listed above is `iwlwifi`. It and the required firmware are included in all recent Ubuntu versions. If you have a problem, please post your own new question.